# Rank() in R excluding zeros

Tags: r

I am trying to duplicated "manually" the example in [this Wikipedia post](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilcoxon_signed-rank_test#Example) using R.

Here is the data:

```
after = c(125, 115, 130, 140, 140, 115, 140, 125, 140, 135)
before = c(110, 122, 125, 120, 140, 124, 123, 137, 135, 145)
sgn = sign(after-before)
abs = abs(after - before)
d = data.frame(after,before,sgn,abs)

   after before sgn abs
1    125    110   1  15
2    115    122  -1   7
3    130    125   1   5
4    140    120   1  20
5    140    140   0   0
6    115    124  -1   9
7    140    123   1  17
8    125    137  -1  12
9    140    135   1   5
10   135    145  -1  10
```

If I try to rank the rows based on the `abs` column, the `0` entry is naturally ranked as `1`:

```
rank = rank(abs)
(d = data.frame(after,before,sgn,abs,rank))

   after before sgn abs rank
1    125    110   1  15  8.0
2    115    122  -1   7  4.0
3    130    125   1   5  2.5
4    140    120   1  20 10.0
5    140    140   0   0  1.0
6    115    124  -1   9  5.0
7    140    123   1  17  9.0
8    125    137  -1  12  7.0
9    140    135   1   5  2.5
10   135    145  -1  10  6.0
```

However, zeros are ignored in the Wilcoxon signed-test.

How can I get R to ignore that row, so as to end up with:

```
   after before sgn abs rank
1    125    110   1  15  7.0
2    115    122  -1   7  3.0
3    130    125   1   5  1.5
4    140    120   1  20  9.0
5    140    140   0   0    0
6    115    124  -1   9  4.0
7    140    123   1  17  8.0
8    125    137  -1  12  6.0
9    140    135   1   5  1.5
10   135    145  -1  10  5.0
```

---

SOLUTION (accepted answer below):

```
after = c(125, 115, 130, 140, 140, 115, 140, 125, 140, 135)
before = c(110, 122, 125, 120, 140, 124, 123, 137, 135, 145)
sgn = sign(after-before)
abs = abs(after - before)
d = data.frame(after,before,sgn,abs)
d$rank = rank(replace(abs,abs==0,NA), na='keep')
d$multi = d$sgn * d$rank

(W=abs(sum(d$multi, na.rm = T)))
9
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Wikipedia article:

> 2. Exclude pairs with **|*x*<sub>2,*i*</sub> − *x*<sub>1,*i*</sub>| = 0**. Let ***N*<sub>*r*</sub>** be the reduced sample size.

We need to *exclude* zeroes. By my thinking, you should replace zeroes with NA, and then specify to [`rank()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/rank.html) that you want to exclude NAs from consideration for ranking. Since you need to return a vector of the same length as the input, you can specify `'keep'` as the argument:

```
d$rank <- rank(replace(abs,abs==0,NA),na='keep');
d;
##    after before sgn abs rank
## 1    125    110   1  15  7.0
## 2    115    122  -1   7  3.0
## 3    130    125   1   5  1.5
## 4    140    120   1  20  9.0
## 5    140    140   0   0   NA
## 6    115    124  -1   9  4.0
## 7    140    123   1  17  8.0
## 8    125    137  -1  12  6.0
## 9    140    135   1   5  1.5
## 10   135    145  -1  10  5.0
```

The subtraction-based solutions will not work if the input vector contains zero zeroes or multiple zeroes.

Comment: I wonder if I can bother you with a follow-up question... When I run the test in R as `wilcox.test(d$after,d$before, paired = T)` I get a `V=27`, or `V=18`, instead of the calculated `9` in the Wikipedia entry. Do you know what I'm missing?

Comment: @Toni I just looked into the source code of `wilcox.test()`, which invokes `stats:::wilcox.test.default()` via S3 dispatch. The culprit is the statement where they actually compute the value of the test statistic: `STATISTIC <- setNames(sum(r[x > 0]), "V")`, where `r` is the correct rank vector and `x` is the (non-absolute) difference between the two sample vectors (`after` and `before`). Going by the Wikipedia article, that sum expression should be `sum(r*sign(x))`, which gives 9. Their expression `sum(r[x>0])` gives 27.

Comment: It looks like there's some disagreement in the statistics world about exactly how this test is supposed to be done; see http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/65844/wilcoxon-rank-sum-test-in-r for example.

Comment: Thanks. Please consider answering the question I posted a few minutes ago.

Answer (score 3):

You could create the new column and then just update the rank where the abs value isn't 0

```
d$rank <- 0  # default value for rows with abs=0
d$rank[d$abs!=0] <- rank(d$abs[d$abs!=0])
```

If you wanted to drop the row completely, you could just do

```
 transform(subset(d, abs!=0), rank=rank(abs))
```

Answer (score 1):

A quick way to do it would be to rank as normal and then do:

```
d$rank <- ifelse(d$rank == 1, 0, d$rank - 1)
```

This switches all ranks of `1` to `0`, and reduces any other ranks by `1`.

Comment: Is this different from `d$rank = d$rank - 1`?

Comment: I suppose not, but the `ifelse` at least gives you the option of subbing in some other value if the script changes. For example if you wanted to insert `NA` values instead.

Comment: @Gregor both are incorrect when there are no zeroes in `abs` I suppose

Comment: @jdobres Checking for rank instead of the values makes this solution irrelevant. Just like my silly comment under the question itself

Comment: Agreed. Which would make MrFlick's solution the most correct.